# Помогите разобраться с объектом

Tags: php, массивы

А точнее если я все правильно понимаю, с массивом объектов! Вообщем из далекого края приходит на страницу JSON:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['same']));
var_dump($data);
```

`var_dump` выдает вот такую строку:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#1759 (2) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
    ["qty"]=> int(2) }
  [1]=> object(stdClass)#1761 (2) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "3"
    ["qty"]=> int(1)
  }
}
```

Правильно, это массив объектов?

Вообщем в чем я уверен, так это то, что там есть `id` и `qty`, то что мне нужно. Номер товара и его количество. Мне нужно этот объект распарсить так, чтобы я по йд достал информацию из базы данных о товаре и вывел на страницу, например (фотку, описание) и рядом вставил количество товара, которое находится в этом объекте.

Вообщем не могу понять как мне это сделать, подтолкните меня в правильном направлении!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так а в чем проблема? У вас ведь уже все есть.

```
$productMap = array(); //здесь будет массив id->qty

//цикл по вашему массиву
foreach($data as $object) {
    $productMap[$object->id] = $object->qty;
}
//по исходным данным массив $productMap теперь имеет вид:
//["2": 2, "3" : 1]

//теперь получим все идентификаторы, чтобы с ними обратиться к базе:
$ids = array_keys($productMap);
//теперь в массиве $ids лежат только id продуктов, в данном случае: ["2", "3"],
//а в $productMap всё еще связка "идентификатор" - "количество"
```

Comment: В цикле делать запрос в базу данных , для вывода мне нужной информации о товаре?

Comment: Можно, но по производительности это будет не лучший вариант. В цикле можно достать все нужные вам id товаров, потом сделать один запрос к базе и достать все товары с нужными идентификаторами. А потом уже с ними делать, что нужно.

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне потом определить к какому товару принадлежит количество qty?

Comment: Я обновил ответ согласно комментариям. Соотношение "id" -> "количество" вы можете хранить, а список идентификаторов для доступа к базе получить отдельно.

Comment: И получается когда я вытягиваю в цикле информацию из базы данных, сравнивать id и если id == то вставляем количество, правильно?

Comment: Да, вполне. Если, конечно, это требуется.